# Use stim to simulate d=3 Bacon-Shor's code

Tags: stim

When I use stim to simulate d=3 Bacon-Shor's code, I can't find the problem with my circuits resulting in the weird DetectorErrorModel.
The initialization and stabilizer measurement circuits are as follow:
[image: layout]

[image: circuits]

I focus on $|0\rangle _L$ memory simulation and choose not to use reset after measurement. So with three rounds of stabilizer measurements, the detectors are

```
...
DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4]
DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3]
...
SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4]
DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3]
...
SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4] rec[-8]
DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3] rec[-7]
...
DETECTOR(0, 0, 1) rec[-9] rec[-6] rec[-8] rec[-5] rec[-7] rec[-4] rec[-13] rec[-17]
DETECTOR(1, 0, 1) rec[-6] rec[-3] rec[-5] rec[-2] rec[-4] rec[-1] rec[-12] rec[-16]
```

some error I can't understand appear in auto-generated DetectorErrorModel like `D0 D4 L0 ^ D1 D5 ^ L0`.

Here is my `stim.Circuit` file and generated error_model:

**circuit.txt**

```
stim.Circuit('''
    R 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
    H 0
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0
    CX 0 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 0 1
    CX 1 2
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 1 2
    H 3
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 3
    CX 3 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 4
    CX 4 5
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 5
    H 6
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 6
    CX 6 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 6 7
    CX 7 8
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 7 8
    H 0
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0
    H 1
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 1
    H 2
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 2
    H 3
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 3
    H 4
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 4
    H 5
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 5
    H 6
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 6
    H 7
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 7
    H 8
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 11 0
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 0
    CX 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    CX 11 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 1
    CX 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 3 4 5 6 7 8
    CX 11 3
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 3
    CX 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 5 6 7 8
    CX 11 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 4
    CX 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 6 7 8
    CX 11 6
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 6
    CX 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 8
    CX 11 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 7
    CX 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 0 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 0 9
    CX 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 3 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 9
    CX 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 4 5 7 8 11 12
    CX 1 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 1 9
    CX 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 4 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 9
    CX 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 5 6 8 11 12
    CX 2 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 2 9
    CX 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 3 4 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 5 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 9
    CX 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 11 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    X_ERROR(0.05) 9
    M 9
    X_ERROR(0.05) 10
    M 10
    X_ERROR(0.05) 11
    M 11
    X_ERROR(0.05) 12
    M 12
    DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4]
    DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3]
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 11 0
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 0
    CX 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 1
    CX 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 3
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 3
    CX 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 4
    CX 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 6
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 6
    CX 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10
    CX 11 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 7
    CX 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 0 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 0 9
    CX 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 3 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 9
    CX 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 4 5 7 8 11 12
    CX 1 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 1 9
    CX 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 4 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 9
    CX 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 5 6 8 11 12
    CX 2 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 2 9
    CX 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 3 4 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 5 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 9
    CX 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 11 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    X_ERROR(0.05) 9
    M 9
    X_ERROR(0.05) 10
    M 10
    X_ERROR(0.05) 11
    M 11
    X_ERROR(0.05) 12
    M 12
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
    DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4]
    DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3]
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 11 0
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 0
    CX 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 1
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 1
    CX 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 2
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 3
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 3
    CX 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 4
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 4
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 4
    CX 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 5
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10
    CX 11 6
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 6
    CX 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 7
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10
    CX 11 7
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 11 7
    CX 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 12 8
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    H 11
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 11
    H 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 12
    CX 0 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 0 9
    CX 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 3 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 3 9
    CX 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 6 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 4 5 7 8 11 12
    CX 1 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 1 9
    CX 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 4 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 4 9
    CX 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 7 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 5 6 8 11 12
    CX 2 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 2 9
    CX 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 3 4 6 7 8 11 12
    CX 5 9
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 5 9
    CX 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.02) 8 10
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.002) 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 11 12
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    X_ERROR(0.05) 9
    M 9
    X_ERROR(0.05) 10
    M 10
    X_ERROR(0.05) 11
    M 11
    X_ERROR(0.05) 12
    M 12
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
    DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-4] rec[-8]
    DETECTOR(1, 0, 0) rec[-3] rec[-7]
    X_ERROR(0.05) 0
    M 0
    X_ERROR(0.05) 1
    M 1
    X_ERROR(0.05) 2
    M 2
    X_ERROR(0.05) 3
    M 3
    X_ERROR(0.05) 4
    M 4
    X_ERROR(0.05) 5
    M 5
    X_ERROR(0.05) 6
    M 6
    X_ERROR(0.05) 7
    M 7
    X_ERROR(0.05) 8
    M 8
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 9 10 11 12
    DETECTOR(0, 0, 1) rec[-9] rec[-6] rec[-8] rec[-5] rec[-7] rec[-4] rec[-13] rec[-17]
    DETECTOR(1, 0, 1) rec[-6] rec[-3] rec[-5] rec[-2] rec[-4] rec[-1] rec[-12] rec[-16]
    OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-9] rec[-8] rec[-7]
''')
```

**error_model.txt**

```
stim.DetectorErrorModel('''
    error(0.07819) D0 D2
    error(0.102128) D0 D4 L0
    error(0.102128) D0 D4 L0 ^ D1 D5 ^ L0
    error(0.0313222) D0 D4 L0 ^ D3 D5 ^ L0
    error(0.07819) D1 D3
    error(0.105303) D1 D5
    error(0.0860003) D2
    error(0.108379) D2 D4 L0
    error(0.117794) D2 D4 L0 ^ D3 D5 ^ L0
    error(0.0159144) D2 D4 L0 ^ D5 ^ L0
    error(0.0860003) D3
    error(0.108379) D3 D5
    error(0.117794) D4 D5
    error(0.0159144) D4 D5 ^ D2
    error(0.07239) D4 D6
    error(0.0313222) D4 D7
    error(0.120844) D4 L0
    error(0.0159144) D4 L0 ^ D2
    error(0.120844) D5
    error(0.07239) D5 D7
    error(0.0159144) D5 ^ D3
    error(0.166418) D6 D7
    error(0.169079) D6 L0
    error(0.0159144) D6 L0 ^ D4 L0
    error(0.166418) D7
    error(0.0159144) D7 ^ D5
    detector(0, 0, 0) D0
    detector(1, 0, 0) D1
    shift_detectors(0, 0, 1) 0
    detector(0, 0, 0) D2
    detector(1, 0, 0) D3
    shift_detectors(0, 0, 1) 0
    detector(0, 0, 0) D4
    detector(1, 0, 0) D5
    detector(0, 0, 1) D6
    detector(1, 0, 1) D7
''')
```

(Sorry for I did not combine some same-type gates into one line so it's a little uncomfortable to read.)
I'm not sure whether I made some mistakes in writing the circuits or there is any error mechanism I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that v1.8.0 is out I can use the new `explain_detector_error_model_errors` feature to find the circuit error causing the symptoms `D0 D4 L0 ^ D1 D5 ^ L0`:

```
import stim
circuit = ...your_circuit...

explained = circuit.explain_detector_error_model_errors(
    dem_filter=stim.DetectorErrorModel("""
        error(1) D0 D4 L0 ^ D1 D5 ^ L0
    """),
    reduce_to_one_representative_error=True,
)

print(explained[0].circuit_error_locations[0])
```

And the simplest way to cause those symptoms is...

```
CircuitErrorLocation {
    flipped_pauli_product: Z3
    Circuit location stack trace:
        (after 0 TICKs)
        at instruction #9 (DEPOLARIZE1) in the circuit
        at target #1 of the instruction
        resolving to DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 3
}
```

A Z error on qubit 3 right after it is hit by a Hadamard in the first layer of Hadamards.

This isn't a logical error, by the way. Keep in mind the two `L0` in `D0 D4 L0 ^ D1 D5 ^ L0` cancel out. It's a not-so-well decomposed `D0 D1 D4 D5`.

Comment: 'Also, you appear to be directly measuring the stabilizers instead of measuring the edges that you're supposed to measure.', Sorry I don't quite understand the meaning of this. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Inm The Bacon-Shor code is made up of 2-body parity measurements. The measurements don't all commute with each other, but you can multiply combinations of them together to recover the stabilizers that are actually used.

Comment: I used the protocol that using one ancilla qubit to make CNOT with other 6 qubits and measure a stabilizer at one time.

Comment: Besides, the encoding procedure should be fault-tolerant. The point is that I can't think of an error can result in symptoms `D0 D1 D4 D5`. When I set only 2 detectors every cycle for Z stabilizer measurement, I think the number of symptoms caused by any single error should be no more than 2.

Comment: @Inn The latest dev release of stim has a `match_errors` command line mode where it lists the circuit errors that cause dem errors. They'll be a python method for it, soon. Keep in mind you have `DEPOLARIZE2` operations, which have a YY term and each Y term can causes two detection events. And furthermore, using six cnots to measure a stabilizer means that if error occurs on the measurement qubit halfway through that process, it will kick out onto three separate data qubits. The only reason you don't have worse errors is there's only four stabilizers to flip!

Comment: @Inn The encoding procedure you used is not fault tolerant. The Bacon-Shor code does have fault tolerant initialization... but you didn't use that.

Comment: I noticed you have added `explain_error` in python api, it's really helpful, Thanks!

Comment: The encoding procedure is adopt from [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03928-y), it says it's FT.

Comment: Huh. Yes, figure 2 (a) does claim that it's fault tolerant. The figure shows an arbitrary state going in, which would not be fault tolerant. But the caption is correct that specifically a Z eigenstate is protected by the time the blue region begins. And I think that's the relevant case for you.

Comment: @Inm updated the answer now that I have hard data on the error

Comment: I check the circuits again and find I set the detector xor between n/n+1 rather than n/n+2 cycle... I debug this and now that it  works well. Thanks again for adding the method to locate error in stim, it should be of help in some situations.

Comment: That results in the detectors being sensitive to errors spanning all the way back to the start of time, right? One way to detect that kind of thing while coding is to make the circuit unnecessarily deep and check if the detector error model has huge terms (terms growing linearly with depth). An early warning sign is decompose_errors=True starts failing when you're confident it should succeed.